# Gcc: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 signal terminated program cc1

Tags: macos, gcc, internals, command-line-tool

I recently updated to MacOS Catalina, and I get this error in compiling a simple hello-world.c program:

```
gcc -o hello_world hello_world.c

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/8.3.0/cc1
Reason: image not found
gcc: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 signal terminated program cc1
Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
```

here some details:

GCC:

```
which gcc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc

gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Xcode:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 11.1
Build version 11A1027
```

Command Line Tools:

```
xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2370.
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Let me know if you need other infos!
Thank for your help!
Kind regards,
Nico

P.S.

```
brew doctor
```

Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
```

software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3.7-config
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3.7m-config
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3-config
```

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
Unexpected header files:

```
/usr/local/include/gmp.h
/usr/local/include/gmpxx.h
/usr/local/include/mpf2mpfr.h
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h
```

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in

```
/usr/local/lib.
```

If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.la
/usr/local/lib/libgmp.la
/usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.la
/usr/local/lib/libgomp.la
/usr/local/lib/libitm.la
/usr/local/lib/libmpc.la
/usr/local/lib/libmpfr.la
/usr/local/lib/libquadmath.la
/usr/local/lib/libssp.la
/usr/local/lib/libssp_nonshared.la
/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.la
/usr/local/lib/libstdc++fs.la
/usr/local/lib/libsupc++.la
/usr/local/lib/libubsan.la
```

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in

```
/usr/local/lib.
```

If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib/libatomic.a
/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a
/usr/local/lib/libgmp.a
/usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.a
/usr/local/lib/libgomp.a
/usr/local/lib/libitm.a
/usr/local/lib/libmpfr.a
/usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a
/usr/local/lib/libssp.a
/usr/local/lib/libssp_nonshared.a
/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a
/usr/local/lib/libstdc++fs.a
/usr/local/lib/libsupc++.a
```

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

```
gtk+
glib-networking
gmp
libidn2
gedit
libsoup
ghostscript
gtk+3
mpfr
python
gtksourceview4
gdk-pixbuf
shared-mime-info
atk
glib
gtk-mac-integration
gspell
libpeas
gnutls
gsettings-desktop-schemas
iso-codes
```

Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in

```
/usr/local/sbin.
```

Consider setting the PATH for example like so:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

and then

```
brew config                 
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.1.13
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: aa043c1d678afd26f50156a83417c296cb9d5a4b
Last commit: 18 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: c6602c5c34968d1d76db31e475af50511ab70a7f
Core tap last commit: 53 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: octa-core 64-bit kabylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 11.0 build 1100
Git: 2.21.0 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 13
macOS: 10.15-x86_64
CLT: 11.0.0.0.1.1567737322
Xcode: 11.1
CLT headers: 11.0.0.0.1.1567737322
```

Comment: Didn't read all of it as it's too long but the Xcode-provided compiler frontend is picking-up and using and Homebrew-provided compiler driver in `/usr/local`.  This is the root of the issue.

Comment: Hi @trojanfoe , so, what I have to write on the terminal? Thanks!

Comment: So to remedy: Homebrew is broken so [uninstall it](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew) and start again.  Start using the word `clang` instead of `gcc` when building stuff (however I do not know *why* Xcode gcc is looking in `/usr/local`).

Comment: I remove homebrew as you said, now what I have to do? Now I try to compile a program that I have on fortran but I can't do it anymore :(

Comment: Ah OK so you need fortran built into Homebrew gcc?  You'll have to reinstall that and continue using `gcc` to build your fortran programs.  Your path should be set-up so that `/usr/local/bin` is towards the start and therefore homebrew gcc will be picked-up first.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'm not an expert in this things, what I have to write on the terminal?

Comment: Well you need to follow Homebrew install docs.  That should show how to set `$PATH`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that.
I reinstalled gcc because I need fortran for my work, but I can't compile on c as before. 
If you could guide me in writing on the terminal would be great